# BigQuery - Significance Performance Difference for Two Tables w/ the Same Schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I observed a significance difference in terms of execution time for the following query for two tables w/ the same schema:

```
SELECT
  VCF.reference_name AS chrm,
  VCF.start AS start,
  VCF.END AS END,
  VCF.reference_bases AS reference_bases,
  VCF.alternate_bases AS alternate_bases,
  CONCAT("hg19_refGene: ",Annotation1.name ),
  Annotation1.name2,
FROM (
  SELECT
    VCF.reference_name,
    VCF.start,
    VCF.END,
    VCF.reference_bases,
    VCF.alternate_bases,
    Annotation1.name,
    Annotation1.name2
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM (
      SELECT
        REPLACE(reference_name, 'chr', '') AS reference_name,
        start,
        END,
        reference_bases,
        alternate_bases
      FROM
        [***genomics-public-data:platinum_genomes.variants***]
      OMIT
        RECORD IF EVERY(call.genotype <= 0))) AS VCF
  JOIN
    [ANOTHER_TABLE] AS Annotation1
  ON
    (Annotation1.chrm = VCF.reference_name)
  WHERE
    (((Annotation1.start >= VCF.start)
        AND (Annotation1.start <= VCF.END))
      OR ((Annotation1.END >= VCF.start)
        AND (Annotation1.END <= VCF.END))
      OR ((Annotation1.start <= VCF.start)
        AND (Annotation1.END >= VCF.start))
      OR ((Annotation1.start <= VCF.END)
        AND (Annotation1.END >= VCF.END))))
```

It takes around **56.0s**, **5.45 GB** processed 
[Job ID: bquijob_217bb63b_15f4a9e559f].

And if I change the above mentioned public table with my own table with the exact same schema and much smaller number of records.

Then it takes around **309.0s** elapsed, **1.06 GB** processed. 
[Job ID: bquijob_40adc8f0_15f4aaab5d0].

BiqQuery folks, would you please check these two jobs? Am I missing any optimization step for creating my own tables?

Comment: Have you submitted a bug on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B)? It sounds like a bug if there is a significant performance difference. (Either provide the job IDs from above or link to this post).

Comment: Reported. Thanks.

Comment: What is `[ANOTHER_TABLE]` ?

Comment: This is a private table, and it doesn't change for these calls: 'gbsc-gcp-project-cba:PublicAnnotationSets.hg19_refGene'